# fancyhdr header left empty before paragraph 1.1 instead of showing chapter title

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

As the title suggest, fancyhdr leaves the header empty when a chapter start with a long text before the first paragraph (paragraph 1.1). I would like to set latex to shows the chapter title in these cases. what should i do?
I am a new latex user so my code right now is a long mess, but i think that the important piece is

```
%% Package Import 

\newenvironment{abstract}{}{}
\usepackage{abstract}

% Typesetting
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}


\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}


\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
```

for the init file, which is then included in the main.tex file

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright,twoside]{book}

\input{tex_parameters/init}
```

`\leftmark` puts the chapter title in everypage while `\chaptername` does not work, maybe because i use `\include{chapterXX}` to import them in the main.tex file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand your problem correctly. If so then here is a possible solution. In the header I check if `\rightmark` is empty. In that case I use `\leftmark`, which should be the chapter title.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\ifempty}[2]{% If #1 is empty, use #2 instead, otherwise use #1
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}} {#2} {#1}%
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \ifempty {\rightmark} {\leftmark}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-12] % long text before first section

\section{First section}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```